# Swiper Products Slider Laravel jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, swiper.js

I'm using Laravel Swiper in Product Page for Product Images. I have two columns for images in database. One is for single image and the other one is for multiple images. I want to slide these images into the swiper.

My view:

```
<head>
  <link href="{{asset('/css/swiper.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-5 product-image-details">
 <input type="hidden" id="check-use-zoom" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="light-box-position" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="product-identify" value="404" />
 <div class="lightbox-container"></div>
 <div class="product-zoom-image">
   <a href="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}" class="cloud-zoom main-image" id="product-cloud-zoom" style="width: 600px; height: 660px;" rel=" showTitle: false, zoomWidth:600,zoomHeight:660, position:'inside', adjustX: 0 ">
     <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}" title="First" alt="First" />
   </a>
 </div>
 @if ($product->images)

  <div class="additional-container">
    <div class="swiper-viewport">
      <div class="additional-images swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <?php $i = 1; ?>
        @foreach (json_decode($product->images, true) as $image)

          <div class="item swiper-slide">
            <a class="cloud-zoom-gallery sub-image" id="product-image-options-" href="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}" title="{{$product->name}}" rel="useZoom: 'product-cloud-zoom', smallImage: '{{ asset('storage/'.$product->image) }}'" data-pos="{{$i}}">
               <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image)}}" title="Multi" alt="Multi" />{{$i}}
             </a>
           </div>
         <?php $i++; ?>
         @endforeach

       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="swiper-pager">
       <div class="swiper-button-next additional-button-next"></div>
       <div class="swiper-button-prev additional-button-prev"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   @endif
</div>

  <script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('/js/swiper.jquery.js')}}"></script>
```

I'm not getting any results.